# adding link_to with image_tag and image path both

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, svg

I am trying to replace the  tag with link_to in my rails application view. 
for replacing I have svg icon, text and link all in one tag. Here is below

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><%= image_tag 'logo.svg', "data-svg-fallback" => image_path('logo.svg'), :align=> "left" ,:style => "padding-right: 5px;" %>
    My Project </a>
```

but I failed to convert the above link to rails link_to

Any suggestion would be great
This is what I am trying
but it is not working

```
  1.  <%= link_to '#' do %>
  My Project<%= image_tag ('logo.svg', "data-svg-fallback" => image_path('logo.svg'), :align=> "left" ,:style => "padding-right: 5px;") %>
  <% end %>
2.   <%= link_to "My Project", home_index_path, :class=> "navbar-brand" do %>
  <%= image_tag('logo.svg'), "data-svg-fallback" => image_path('logo.svg'), :align=> "left" ,:style => "padding-right: 5px"; %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space after image_tag.

```
<%= link_to '#' do %>
  My Project <%= image_tag('logo.svg', "data-svg-fallback" => image_path('logo.svg'), :align=> "left" ,:style => "padding-right: 5px;") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `image_path` you have to use `asseth_path`.

Try this:

```
<%= link_to '#' do %>
  My Project <%= image_tag('logo.svg', "data-svg-fallback" => asset_path('logo.svg'), :align=> "left" ,:style => "padding-right: 5px;") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it is not working ...gives errors
 syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

Comment: Space after image_tag was problem. Updated code..or you can also remove brackets as ugo mare suggested..

Comment: I edited my answer cause It's a better practice to use brackets in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `asset_path` do set the path of your svg inside the data attribute like so

```
<%= link_to "index.html", class: "navbar-brand" do %>
       <%= image_tag "logo.svg", data: { svg_fallback => asset_path("logo.svg") }, align: "left", style: "padding-right: 5px;" %> My Project
<% end %>
```